# Read and write XML in MATLAB

Tags: xml, matlab, struct

I would like to do exactly what [`readstruct`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readstruct.html) and [`writestruct`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writestruct.html) do in MATLAB 2020b :

```
S = readstruct(filename)
writestruct(S,filename)
```

But for MATLAB 2019, these methods don't exist. How can I accomplish the same behaviour in R2019?

Comment: It would be helpful to describe what that behaviour is, at least in brief, so the question is self-contained for people without those functions

Comment: What types of variables are in the struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, if they do exactly the same as `readstruct` and `writestruct`, but there are two similar functions available in MathWorks' *File Exchange*:

`struct2xml`: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28639-struct2xml

`xml2struct`: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct